# Getting undefined method `when_visible' for #<Array:0x3db6090> (NoMethodError) in PageObject

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, page-object-gem

I’m getting Getting undefined method `when_visible' for # (NoMethodError) when I used built –in method from PageObject Ruby gem. Here is my code:

```
class HomePage
  include PageObject

  links(:search_types, :css => ".search-type")

  def select_search_type
    search_types_elements.when_visible(timeout=10)
    search_types_elements.find { |type| if type.text=='Resort'; type.click; break end }
  end
end
```

Could someone please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you want to wait for when you do `search_types_elements.when_visible(timeout=10)`? Are you wanting to just wait for at least one element to exist, one with the text "Resort" to exist, something else?

Comment: I upgraded your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to reflect discussion.**

page-object gem handles the plural of its basic accessors. Page-object ultimately generates

```
search_types_elements = @browser.find_elements(:css, ".search-type")
```

so you will need to follow it with something like (**Updated**)

```
search_types_elements.find { |type| 
  type.when_visible(timeout=10)
  if type.text=='Resort'; type.click; break end
}
```

You should add something to the page class constructor to wait for the page to completely load.  Unfortunately, there isn't a simple way to do this.  Much depends on the page specifics.  I usually start by waiting for the jquery queue to have zero length.  Something like this:

```
WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(lambda s:  s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

Comment: I didn't downgrade your question.  Stuff happens.

Comment: The `links` method is valid. It is dynamically defined in [`accessors.rb`](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/accessors.rb#L1438-L1465).

Comment: Yes you are right (I learn something everyday).  It ultimately generates search_types_elements = @browser.find_elements() so you will need to follow it with something like search_types_elements.each do |element| #some action on element end

Comment: I think the problem is how do you wait for a collection of elements to become visible? But like I commented on the question, does that mean waiting for 1 or n elements to appear?

Comment: Justin, Yes.  Visible is an element property, not a collection of elements property. It would depend on how those elements are loaded.  In the page object class you could wait for the jquery queue to be empty.  It would take an intimate knowledge of the page to really know.

Comment: If you know in advance that there should be five elements then perhaps you could do something like this: wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout ==> 15) wait.until( search_types_elements.count == 5 )